# Replace Underscore (_) on Space ( )

Tags: php, title, customization, underscore

I use the plugin "Auto Post With Image Upload"
For example I load an image with name "Image_Name"
then plugin creates a post with name "Image_Name"

Now the question: How to remove Underscore (_) in post title
Tell me "where to dig"? 
I know that there are such a function "str_replace". Where apply it?

Here is a piece of code:

```
$postData = array(
    'post_title' => $attachment->post_title,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_content' => $image_tag,
    'post_category' => array('0'),
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```

P.S. I not quite understand php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you need to use `str_replace`. See details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)

So the correct code would be:

```
$postData = array(
'post_title' => str_replace('_', ' ', $attachment->post_title),
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_content' => $image_tag,
'post_category' => array('0'),
'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```